# Google Playstore showing "Partially Upgradable APK" warning

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to upgrade my exiting set of multiple apks (split on cpu architecture) to the playstore and it's coming up with a warning message suggesting *Some users of the exiting apk may not be able to upgrade to any of the new APKs added in this release*

Here's the screenshot of the same.

[image]

Any suggestions as to what it exactly implies and what could be the reason for the same?

Answer (score 0):

The reason may vary, you can check your Google Play Console **Active artifacts**, it will shows the different of each apk version.

[image]

If **Native platforms** has different, then it means the old apk support more phones processor architecture than current uploaded apk, so old user used that phones will not able to update the apk. In this case you can uncompress apk to know this arch native code listed as directories in `lib/`.